# Collision: "death" animation

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision-detection

I have a Corona SDK project that tries to play a death animation for enemies:

```
elseif name1 == "enemy" or name2 == "enemy" then
    if name1 == "enemy" then
        if player.y < event.object1.y-(event.object1.height*0.5) then 
            display.remove(event.object1); event.object1 = nil
            changeText(10)
        else
            print( "trigger animation" )
            event.object1:setSequence("explode") --Not working
            event.object1:play()
            gameOver()      
        end
    else
```

So in the `else`, it should trigger the animation change but nothing happens. The debug `print` does occur though.

The sprite sheet looks like:

```
local enemySheet = graphics.newImageSheet("images/enemies.png", sheetInfoEnemy:getSheet() )
local enemySprite = 
{ name="stand", start=1, count=31, time = 1000, loopCount = 0 },
{ name="explode", start=32, count=25, time=800, loopCount=1 }
```

And the normal `stand` animation plays just fine.

What am I missing? The collision is happening, `gameOver` is being called, but the `explode` animation is not playing.

Comment: Lua can't assign multiple values to a single variable. enemySprite will just get the first value (the table with stand as the name). Maybe you meant to assign a table of values?

Comment: @rpattiso Wow you're right. I was missing a `{ }`. Feel free to make that an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is assigning only the first table to `enemySprite`:

```
local enemySprite = 
   { name="stand", start=1, count=31, time = 1000, loopCount = 0 },
   { name="explode", start=32, count=25, time=800, loopCount=1 }
```

Lua will evaluate both tables, but the second is silently discarded on assignment. To fix this, store both tables in another table:

```
local enemySprite = {
   { name="stand", start=1, count=31, time = 1000, loopCount = 0 },
   { name="explode", start=32, count=25, time=800, loopCount=1 } 
}
```

You may need to adjust the code that uses `enemySprite` (which isn't shown) to use the new table.